# Detect if UIScrollView is scrolling

Tags: ios

I'm looking to detect if (not when) a `UIScrollView` is scrolling.

i.e.

```
BOOL isScrolling = myscrollview.scrolling;
```

How would I go about implementing this? `.dragging` and `.decelerating` do not apply when `setContentOffset:animated:` is used.

Comment: How about `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method?

Comment: That only answers the "when".

Comment: A bit convoluted, but depending on the reason why you want this information, you can look at the mode of the main run loop. For instance, in no scroll view is currently scrolling or being dragged, your main run loop will probably be in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`. If any scroll view is scrolling/being dragged, it will be in a different mode, part of `NSRunLoopCommonModes`. For instance, if you want to wait for scrolling to end to do something, you can use `CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, block);`

Comment: Hmmm ok thanks but I'm not going there... I guess the lesson learned is to avoid the ".scrolling" approach. For some reason `setContentOffset:animated:` with animated set to NO would call `scrollViewDidScroll` but not `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`... it's just not fair...

Comment: @Jonny: What was your solution?

Comment: I don't remember, but judging from my last comment, I probably found (or tried to find) a way to do things differently, ie not having to know if a scrollview is scrolling or not.

Comment: @Guillaume That's great knowledge, thanks. Is there any way to get a notification from the `NSRunLoop` when its mode changes?

Answer (score 23):

*EDIT: This method seems to have stopped working since iOS 14. I'll try and see if I can find an alternative method, and I'll update this answer if I do.*

---

This may be a slightly dodgy way of doing it, but I've used it in my code before and it hasn't failed me yet. :)

**Swift**

```swift
let isScrolling = scrollView.layer.animation(forKey: "bounds") != nil
```

**Objective-C**

```objectivec
BOOL isScrolling = [scrollView.layer animationForKey:@"bounds"] != nil;
```

In addition to `self.contentOffset` the offset of a `UIScrollView` is stored in the `bounds.origin` property of the `UIView` as well (I guess since it's a bit more convenient in lower-level code). When you call `[setContentOffset:animated:]`, it's passing that off to the `UIScrollView` as a `CABasicAnimation`, manipulating the `bounds` property.

Granted, this check will also return true if the shape of the scroll view itself is animating. In which case you may need to actually pull the bounds object out of the animation (`[CAAnimation toValue]`) and do a manual compare to see if `origin` itself is changing at all.

It's not the most elegant solution, but I like being able to avoid having to make use of the scroll view delegate whenever possible. Especially if the scroll view in question might be a subclass explicitly vending its delegate as part of its public API. :)

Comment: Thanks for that answer TiM, do you know if it passes Apple's review process ?

Comment: No worries Randy! Yep! It does. It's not touching any private APIs. I've had an app with this line of code in the App Store for over 2 years. :)

Comment: Look's like it isn't working in iOS 14 `scrollView.layer.animationKeys` gives me nothing

Comment: @Cy-4AH Ahh you're right! I tested and confirmed it too! Hmm okay. I'll have a think about this and see if I can come up with any potential alternative ways of checking.

Answer (score 12):

Not a very clean solution .. but should be the most reliable:

```
var isScrolling = false

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isScrolling = true
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate { scrollViewDidEndScrolling(scrollView) }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollViewDidEndScrolling(scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollViewDidEndScrolling(scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrolling(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isScrolling = false
}
```

Comment: I second this. This is 100% the most reliable way of detecting scrolling. If your implementation allows you to access the scroll view's delegate, you should definitely consider this method first.

Comment: This can be very wrong. 1 because begin dragging doesn't mean that is scrolling. I could stay still without leaving the touch. 2 because did end scrolling did end srolling animation I think might be called multiple times when you already called X times setContentOffset:animated:. Which means the there are multiple animations 1 next to the other. That have been triggered and you are setting isScrolling to false after the first one completes.

Comment: Basically `isScrolling` means that the user started interacting with the scrollView and didn't finish yet. That way you can know if is it safe to change the content.

Answer (score 7):

I usually do this by setting a boolean variable in the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` events.

[UIScrollView Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate)

Comment: I'm not using dragging... even if I would I guess it's still wouldn't catch setContentOffset:animated

Comment: You can also implement `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` which will be called when the animation launched by `setContentOffset:animated:` ends...

Comment: @Guillaume: I tested it and it works if you use an animation. Do you use a property which is set the same time you call `setContentOffset`? Or is there another possibility to check when the scrolling started? Is there also a possibility without using animation?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

use a flag to save current scroll status?
it could only solve the setContentOffset:animated: problem.

The "scrolling" is just an effect, there are many ways that make a scrollview "scrolling", e.g. set the content offset continuously. So there should be NO answer for this question.